# request response data when using taurus junit-xml module

Tags: junit, jmeter, taurus

I am trying to clean-up the jmeter docker+ci pipeline of our functional tests. I see taurus has a clean way to run jmeter scripts in a container and it does the heavy lifting of downloading the version of jmeter I want + installing the plugins my scripts use - excellent.

Now I need to generate the reports in junit.xml so I could keep the reporting consistent. Up until now I was using a modified fork of https://github.com/tguzik/m2u to convert jtl reports to junit.xml

Appreciate any help with how I can get request, response (code & body) for all samples onto junit.xml (at least for the failed samples)?

I tried few variations of taurus yaml ...

```
reporting:
  - module: console
  - module: final_stats
    summary: true
    percentiles: true
    test-duration: true
  - module: junit-xml
    filename: report/report.xml
    data-source: sample-labels
```

---

```
reporting:
  - module: console
  - module: final_stats
    summary: true
    percentiles: true
    test-duration: true
  - module: passfail
  - module: junit-xml
    filename: report/report.xml
    data-source: pass-fail
```

Also added certain passfail criteria variations on the passfail module. did not help

---

After fiddling with this for few hours, I believe there is no clean way to get anything meaningful onto the junit .xml report from the junit-xml module in taurus. It appears barebone. I also noticed that it could mess up the default jenkins junit plugin test result summary.

So I settled down with the following yaml setting and continued to use m2u.jar to convert the jtl to junit.xml

```
    modules:
    jmeter:
      path: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/bin/jmeter
      download-link: https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-{version}.zip
      version: 5.3  
      force-ctg: true 
      detect-plugins: true
      plugins:
      - jpgc-json=2.2
      - jmeter-ftp
      - jpgc-casutg
      xml-jtl-flags:
        xml: true
        fieldNames: true
        time: true
        timestamp: true
        latency: true
        connectTime: false
        success: true
        label: true
        code: true
        message: true
        threadName: true
        dataType: false
        encoding: false
        assertions: true
        subresults: true
        responseData: false
        samplerData: false
        responseHeaders: false
        requestHeaders: true
        responseDataOnError: true
        saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage: true
        bytes: true
        threadCounts: false
        url: true

execution:
- write-xml-jtl: full
  scenario:
    script: v_jmxfilename
    properties:
      environment: v_env

reporting:
  - module: console
  - module: final_stats
    summary: true
    percentiles: true
    test-duration: true
#  - module: junit-xml
#    filename: report/junit-report.xml
#    data-source: sample-labels
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [JUnit-XML-Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) documentation currently this is not possible:

> This reporter provides test results in JUnit XML format parseable by Jenkins JUnit Plugin. Reporter has two options:
>
> - `filename` (full path to report file, optional. By default xunit.xml in artifacts dir)
> - `data-source` (which data source to use: sample-labels or pass-fail)
>
> If sample-labels used as source data, report will contain urls with test errors. If pass-fail used as source data, report will contain Pass/Fail criteria information. Please note that you have to place pass-fail module in reporters list, before junit-xml module.

Taurus is not only for JMeter, it supports many more tools and not all of them provide possibility to store request and response data so the options I can think of are in:

1. Add a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) to your Test Plan and choose what metrics you need to store into a separate file, the easiest one for using is [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)
2. Use [ShellExec Service](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ShellExec/) to run your `m2u.jar` from Taurus config YAML